# Why is dbmigrations failing?

Tags: grails

I'm attempting to use the dbmigrations plugin(1.4) with my app (Grails 2.3.11), when attempting to add a changeset I receive the following error relating to requestCache.  Does anyone know why it is failing?

```
Error running script dbm-gorm-diff add-sausage.groovy -add: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestCache': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'requestMatcher' of bean class [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache]: Bean property 'requestMatcher' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter? (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Thanks

Comment: if this is no genertic problem e.g. to that version, then please consider adding the actual diff and maybe the domain(-change) that leads to that diff

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved..

My IDE (IntelliJ) was adding an additional classpath reference to jdom.jar

Removing this reference from the 'run configuration' of my grails interactive mode cleared things up.